# Resize 256x256 image to a larger dimension PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to resize images in bulk with an original dimension of 256x256. Now I want it to be bigger with a 400x400 dimension.

Here's my code:

> ```
> from PIL import Image
> import pathlib
>
> maxsize = (400, 400)
> input_dir = "directory_string_here"
> path_list = pathlib.Path(input_dir).rglob('*.jpg')
>
> for path in path_list:
>     output_dir = str(path).replace('input','output')
>     
>     with Image.open(path) as img:
>        img.resize(maxsize)
>        img.save(output_dir, dpi=(300,300))
>        print(str(path) + ":     done")
> ```

Now, when I run the code, the images are not in 400x400 dimension but they are still in the original 256x256 dimension. I tried to set maxsize to (200, 200) and it did resized the image to 200x200. Is there a way I could achieve this 400x400 dimension?

Comment: `Image.resize` doesn't work in-place, you need to save back the result, i.e. the correct usage is `img = img.resize(maxsize)`. Hence, I doubt that resizing to `(200, 200)` actually worked, when the code didn't change except for `maxsize`.

Answer (score 0):

One way of resizing your image to higher dimensions is through interpolation. You can use OpenCV library to do so with following code.

```
dim = (400, 400)
resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```